# tilemap for windows phone in xna

Tags: c#, xna

I'm tring to do tile map for windows phone using stream file this thing work to me in  game for windows but it's not working for windows phone i'm using xna  any one can help me please

```
public void LoadMapData(string name)
{
    string path = "leveles/" + name + ".txt";

    // Width and height of our tile array
    int width = 0;
    int height = File.ReadLines(path).Count();

    StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(path);
    string line = sReader.ReadLine();
    string[] tileNo = line.Split(',');

    width = tileNo.Count();
    mapLength = width * 40;
    // Creating a new instance of the tile Coin
    tileMap = new char[height, width];
    sReader.Close();

    // Re-initialising sReader
    sReader = new StreamReader(path);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        line = sReader.ReadLine();
        tileNo = line.Split(',');

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            tileMap[y, x] = Convert.ToChar(tileNo[x]);
        }
    }
    sReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: attempt to access the method failed system.io.streamwriter..ctor(system.string)

Comment: I'm not sure how you're having an issue with streamwriter as you don't appear to be using one in the code you've given. Files on phones work different to on the desktop. Give this [article a read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714087(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: i want to convert the text file to 2D aryy ho can i do in windows phone can you help?

Comment: You seem to be doing that already. The only changes you'll probably need to make will be around working with the files.

Comment: i know but how to work with file in windows phone that's my problem